# Uninstalling Xcode 3.2.6 from Lion 10.7.2

Tags: xcode, macos, osx-lion, uninstallation

I've installed xCode 3.2.6 on my Lion 10.7.2.

After install I can't find the xCode icon to launch it. I've got to know 3.2.6 doesn't support Lion.

However, the worst thing happen when I tried to uninstall it with

```
sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all
```

Unfortunately uninstall-devtools wasn't there. I'm stuck middle of nowhere.

Does anybody have any idea how to uninstall it and install xCode 4.2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools does not exist skip that step.

Delete the /Develop folder if it exists.

Install xCode 4.2. Th eXcode icon will be in /Developer/Applications

The Xcode latest beta is even easier to install, get it if you have access.

Answer (score 4):

Following command fire on terminal and remove the all files and folder of xcode

```
sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all
```

also more information and show log of the uninstal so go refrence [link here](http://sugartin.info/2011/12/02/how-to-fullycompletely-uninstallremove-xcode4/)

Comment: I've told you, I couldn't find uninstall-devtools doesn't work, because Its not there.. :(

Answer (score 1):

If you install Xcode 3 from the GUI on Lion, you'll end up with a bunch of random tools but not the actual Xcode Toolset. In that case, you can use the uninstall-dev-tools located in /Library/Developer/Shared (rather than /Developer/Library).

[image: Xcode installer run via double-clicking mpkg]

You can fully install XCode 3 on Lion via the Terminal with the following commands:

```
export COMMAND_LINE_INSTALL=1
open "/Volumes/Xcode and iOS SDK/Xcode and iOS SDK.mpkg"
```

[image: Xcode installer run from terminal]

Answer (score 0):

careful: if you work in ruby, you better stay with xCode 4.1