# Issue with uninstalling Xcode 3.2 on Mountain Lion

Tags: xcode, macos, uninstallation

I just upgraded to Mountain Lion (from Snow Leopard) so as to take advantage of Xcode 4.

Before installing Xcode 4, I would like to remove Xcode 3 (not required, but want to clean up before moving on).

The standard method of removing Xcode 3 is:

```
$ sudo <Xcode>/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all
```

However, when I issue this command, even from within the `/Library` folder, the only thing that happens is I get a `"command not found"` after entering my password.

I can see `uninstall-devtools` in Finder, so I know it's there.  I just can't execute it for some reason.  I've tried every possible way of running the uninstall tools.

Assistance is greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If the file really is there, type `sudo` in the terminal window (with a trailing space), drag and drop the `uninstall-devtools` file on the window, then append `--mode=all`. That should clear any chance you have to make a typo or any other mistake.

Comment: Not sure why that made a difference, but it worked.  Thank you so much!

Comment: You know you needed to replace the string `<Xcode>` in that command with the directory where Xcode 3 is installed?  The default is `/Developer`

Answer (score 0):

Similarly to information I found in another [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8986592/uninstalling-xcode-3-2-6-from-lion-10-7-2) article, my laptop's old XCode 3.2 didn't even have the `uninstall-tools` utility.

So it worked fine for me to simply delete the `XCode.app` folder.